# Выделение памяти под двумерный массив Си

Tags: c, массивы, память

Выделите память под двумерный динамический массив — матрицу — таким образом, чтобы данные все строки этой матрицы гарантированно располагались в оперативной памяти друг за другом. Просто malloc(n*m*sizeof(int)) не подойдёт, надо именно двумерный массив. Язык: C

Comment: "Просто malloc(n\*m\*sizeof(int)) не подойдёт" - почему? Это вполне себе способ организации двумерного массива, довольно популярный причём.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблем... Выделяйте именно так - `malloc(N*M*sizeof(int))`, а вот дальше...

```
int * data = malloc(N*M*sizeof(int));
int ** a = malloc(N*sizeof(int*));
for(int i = 0; i< N; ++i)
    a[i] = data + M*i;
```

Все, все данные лежат подряд, обращение `a[i][j]` работает корректно - что еще нужно? :)

И освобождать память проще -

```
free(a[0]);
free(a);
```